# Sending a curl and put HTTP command at once java

Tags: java, http

I cannot figure out how to use java to send this (or similar statements) nor can I find a tutorial. Can anyone help? Here is what I need to send:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth <access_token>' \
-X PUT https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_user1/blocks/test_user_troll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpClient from apache's httpcomponents. 
More details here : https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: Looks like it will work, thanks!